# Pagination not working for logged out users Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming

For Logged in users pagination is working fine. But for non logged in users, it shows pagination but it does not work. When you click page 2, it shows

> "Sorry no posts found"

Here is the [link](https://goflow.io/resources)

Theme used is [ultimatum theme](https://ultimatumtheme.com/)

Below is the code

```
$query = array(
         'posts_per_page' => (int) $count,
         'post_type'      => $post,
         'orderby'        => $orderby,
         'order'          => $order,
     );
if(isset($instance['pagination']) && $instance['pagination']!='false'){
           $pagged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
           $query['paged'] = $pagged;
     }
$r = new WP_Query( $query );
if ( $r->have_posts() ):
               while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post();
         /// Some code here
             endwhile;
               if(isset($instance['pagination']) && $instance['pagination']!='false'){
                   echo '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
                   ult_custom_numeric_posts_nav($r->max_num_pages,$pagged);
                   echo '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
               }
           endif;
```

Comment: Since the pagination uses a function from the theme - `ult_custom_numeric_posts_nav()` I suggest you go to their support forum and ask them.

Comment: Also, what the heck is `:disappointed:` in your code? If you've edited your code to paste here, you should ensure that it is exactly as used on your site, otherwise how are we to know that's not the cause?

Comment: @Peter edited the question , sorry it was a typo

Comment: Still have a typo on that line then as you haven't closed the if's `(` before the `:` - also same on the `if(isset($instance`... line so that might actually be the error.

Comment: @Peter nope brackets are fine

Comment: Oops, sorry - didn't read it properly. `if ( $r->have_posts() :` is still wrong though: `if ( $r->have_posts() ) :`